# PHP não encontra arquivos quando executado no terminal

Tags: php, xampp, php-cli

Eu executo o arquivo `x` normalmente, nele eu incluo através de `require_once` vários outros arquivos, e através do navegador eu o executo normalmente.

Porém quando eu executo o arquivo pelo terminal ele não encontra os mesmo arquivos, dá error no require_once, por que? Como fixar isso?

Exemplo de error

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../../../../../x.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/versions/actual/includes/servers/php/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar variáveis globais:
`define('DIR', dirname(__DIR__));
 define('ROOT', __DIR__);`
Quando você executa por algum servidor **ampp** você está executando o projeto como se fosse uma pasta, quando executa pelo terminal a pasta acaba sendo a raiz do servidor, assim você perde as referencias do tipo `../../`.
 Com as variáveis globais você sempre vai ter um caminho absoluto onde seus arquivos podem estar assim podendo referenciar `require_once ROOT.'/pasta/arquivo.php'`